# How to submit a form when a different button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `Save` button which by default, submits a form. However, what I need to do is (in some circumstances, which are omitted for this question) instead open up a dialog when that `Save` button is clicked. Inside that dialog, the `Yes` button on will submit the form. The problem that I am wrestling with currently is applying the "submit" function of the form to the button.

```
form = document.getElementsByClassName('form_submit')[0];
formSubmitFunc = form.onSubmit;

// prevent the form from submitting normally, this will be done by the dialog
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

confirmDlgConfirmBtn.on('click', function() {
  console.log('yes');
  formSubmitFunc();
});

confirmDlgCancelBtn.on('click', function() {
  console.log('no');
  confirmDlg.hide();
})

saveButton.on('click', function() {
  saveButton.disabled = false;
  console.log('save');
  confirmDlg.show();
});
```

Whenever I click on the `confirmDlgConfirmBtn`, instead of the form submitting as hoped for, I receive an error that reads as

> Uncaught TypeError: o is not a function at ...

I have also tried setting `formSubmitFunc = form.submit;` amongst many others but cannot seem to get the default form submit function to execute when `confirmDlgConfirmBtn` is clicked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am mostly guessing here, but I think your problem lies in

```
// prevent the form from submitting normally, this will be done by the dialog
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

This should always prevent the form from being submitted, even when you are triggering it programmatically.

Instead, try to prevent the event default in the button click listener. I am also not completely sure about how you submit the form. [Try submitting it directly with the `submit()` method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp)

```
form = document.getElementsByClassName('form_submit')[0];


confirmDlgConfirmBtn.on('click', function() {
  console.log('yes');
  form.submit(); // using submit function
  confirmDlg.hide(); // you probably also want to hide the dialog when the form is submitted
});

confirmDlgCancelBtn.on('click', function() {
  console.log('no');
  confirmDlg.hide();
})

saveButton.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // preventing the form submit here should work
  saveButton.disabled = false;
  console.log('save');
  confirmDlg.show();
});
```

Comment: Yup, this was the answer that I needed to solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with only HTML like:

```html
<form id='myForm'>
  ...
</form>

<input type='submit' form='myForm'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jquery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Submit Form</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#saveBtn").click(function(){        
        $("#myForm").submit(); // Submit the form
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/examples/html/action.php" method="post" id="myForm">
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="first-name">
        <button type="button" id="submitBtn">Submit Form</button>
    </form>
  <button type="button" id="saveBtn">Save</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Check the document for more guidance
[Click Here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-submit-a-form-using-jquery.php)